# How to remove Hyper Link in XAxis name in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

How to remove the hyper link in the xaxis name. Is there any property in the xaxis lable or do we need to write any function to remove the hyper link.

In the link below how to remove hyper link in the Animals.

```
{
"chart":{"defaultSeriesType":"column"},
"plotOptions":{"column":{"borderWidth":0}},
"series":[
    {"data":[{"x":1.435689E12,"y":6.0,"drilldown":"All-1.435689E12"}],"name":"All","type":"column","tooltip":{"xDateFormat":"%m/%d/%Y"}},
    {"data":[{"x":1.435689E12,"y":2.0,"drilldown":"ABCD-1.435689E12"}],"name":"ABCD","type":"column","tooltip":{"xDateFormat":"%m/%d/%Y"}},
    {"data":[{"x":1.435689E12,"y":1.0,"drilldown":"EFGH-1.435689E12"}],"name":"EFGH","type":"column","tooltip":{"xDateFormat":"%m/%d/%Y"}},
    {"data":[{"x":1.435689E12,"y":2.0,"drilldown":"IJKL-1.435689E12"}],"name":"IJKL","type":"column","tooltip":{"xDateFormat":"%m/%d/%Y"}}],
"title":{"text":"Artifact Created"},
"xAxis":[
    {"minTickInterval":8.64E7,"type":"datetime","labels":{"rotation":45.0},"dateTimeLabelFormats":{"day":"%m/%d/%Y"},"title":   {"text":"Date"},"showEmpty":false},
    {"type":"category","id":"drilldown"}],
"yAxis":[
    {"min":0.0,"title":{"text":"Count"},"showEmpty":false},
    {"labels":{"enabled":false},"title":{"text":""},"id":"drilldown","gridLineWidth":0}],
"drilldown":
    {"series":[
        {"data":[{"y":1.0,"name":"artf1001"},{"y":1.0,"name":"artf1002"},{"y":1.0,"name":"artf1003"},{"y":1.0,"name":"artf1004"},   {"y":1.0,"name":"artf1005"},{"y":1.0,"name":"artf1006"}],"name":"All","type":"column","id":"All-1.435689E12","xAxis":"drilldown","yAxis":"drilldown"},
        {"data":[{"y":1.0,"name":"artf1004"},{"y":1.0,"name":"artf1005"}    ],"name":"ABCD","type":"column","id":"ABCD-1.435689E12","xAxis":"drilldown","yAxis":"drilldown"},
        {"data":[{"y":1.0,"name":"artf1001"}],"name":"EFGH","type":"column","id":"EFGH-1.435689E12","xAxis":"drilldown","yAxis":"drilldown"},
        {"data":[{"y":1.0,"name":"artf1002"},{"y":1.0,"name":"artf1003"}    ],"name":"IJKL","type":"column","id":"IJKL-1.435689E12","xAxis":"drilldown","yAxis":"drilldown"}]
    }
}
```

[The issue can be seen by clicking this link](http://jsfiddle.net/29m88j5h/)

Comment: Drilldown should work only by clicking the column not by the x-axis label.

Answer (score 2):

The simples way is overwrite tick drilldown function as empty.

```
Highcharts.Tick.prototype.drillable = function () {};
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/r2u6spa9/